# Limit the space components take

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

How can I restrict the space that a component takes so that it only takes as much space as need when displayed? I am getting strangely big buttons and stuff when added to panels.

Comment: can you post some sample code so that we can see how you're building the panel?

Comment: You need to play around with other layout managers (e.g. `FlowLayout`). I'm going to assume that you're seeing this behavior with `BorderLayout`.

Comment: @latusaki, Yep, you've got a layout manager problem. If you want to continue using such layout managers, I suggest you place your components on something such as a `JComponent` or `JPanel` and add those directly to the container. That way, the panels will expand and your components will keep their preferred size.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @mre _the panels will expand and your components will keep their preferred size_ only if the panel's LayoutManager sizes them to their respective pref ;-) Use a decent layoutManager on the actual container and be happy (instead of inappropriate nesting ...)

Comment: Well at this moment I'm only using GridLayout and FlowLayout(and Border but rarely)... I know about CardLayout which isn't needed in my case. Are there any other Layouts I should have in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to take a look at [Resizing components java swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

If you can provide us with some code than we can handle the problem specifically.